# ggplot conflict between fill and scale_fill_discrete/plot legend

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'm tinkering with geom_point trying to plot the following code. I have converted cars$vs to a factor with discrete levels so that I can visualize both levels of that variable in different colors by assigning it to "fill" in the ggplot aes settings.

```
cars <- mtcars
cars$vs <- as.factor(cars$vs)

ggplot(cars,aes(x = mpg, y = disp, fill = vs)) +
  geom_point(size = 4) +
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Test")
```

[image: The result is this:]

As you can see, the graph does not differentiate between both "fill" conditions via color. However, it preserves the legend label I have specified in scale_fill_discrete.

Alternatively, I can plot the following (same code, but instead of "fill", use "color")

```
cars <- mtcars
cars$vs <- as.factor(cars$vs)

ggplot(cars,aes(x = mpg, y = disp, color = vs)) +
  geom_point(size = 4) +
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Test")
```

[image]

As you can see, using "color" instead of "fill" differentiates between the levels of the factor via color, but seems to override any changes I make to the legend title using scale_fill_discrete.

Am I using "fill" incorrectly? How can I plot different levels of a factor in different colors using this method *and* have control over the plot legend vis scale_fill_discrete?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are using `color` as mapping, you can use `scale_color_*` to change the corresponding attributes instead of `scale_fill_*`:

```
ggplot(cars,aes(x = mpg, y = disp, color = vs)) +
      geom_point(size = 4) +
      scale_color_discrete(name = "Test")
```

[image]

Comment: that totally works! I was puzzled because using "fill" (rather than "color") had worked in previous code. Could you perhaps clarify how fill wouldn't work in this case? Is there a way it could?

Comment: Yes the function to use corresponds to the mapping i.e. `color, fill, group` you are using. If you are using `color`, use `scale_color_*`, if you are using `fill`, use `scale_fill_*`, etc.

Comment: that makes sense, however, when using `fill` and `scale_fill_discrete`, it does not work. However, using `color` and `scale_color_discrete` does. Why does the first method not work, and the second one does?

Comment: As explained in @Gregor's answer, the `fill` is to fill the color of the interior of a geometrical object, a point with default shape is 0 dimension, so it doesn't have interior to fill. `color`, on the other hand, defines the color of the boundary of the object, the point is the boundary for itself. so it will work.

Answer (score 4):

To use a `fill` with `geom_point` you should use a fill-able shape:

```
ggplot(cars,aes(x = mpg, y = disp, fill = vs)) +
  geom_point(size = 4, shape = 21) +
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Test")
```

See `?pch`, which shows that shapes 21 to 25 can be colored and filled with different colors.`ggplot` will not use the `fill` unless the shape is one that is fill-able. This behavior has changed a bit in different versions, as seen in [the NEWS file](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/master/NEWS).

There's no reason to use `fill` with `geom_point` unless you want the outline and fill colors of the points to be different, so the other answer recommending `color` is probably what you want.

Comment: Interesting! I never had to deal with the `shape` argument before. However, this method results in circles with black outlines. How can I remove the black outlines?

Comment: Ah, it looks like `color = na` does the job.